# Requests.get not saving images on the webpage

Tags: python, python-requests

when I right click a page and click save as and save it as html, it saves everything on the page, including images. However, when I use python's requests.get, it saves the html page without saving the images. They appear as broken links, like so:

[Broken images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sKtv.png)

Instead of like so:

[Working images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3Wp0.png)

How can I get requests.get to get all the data on the webpage? Appreciate any advice.

Edit: This is the code I'm using to scrape the website:

```
for link in aosa1:
    res=requests.get("http://aosabook.org/en/"+link)
    print(res.status_code)
    print(len(res.text))
    res.raise_for_status()

    playfile=open(link,'wb')
    for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
        playfile.write(chunk)
    playfile.close
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't understand how HTML works.  Those images are not part of the page.  When a browser downloads an HTML file, it then scans the HTML looking for `<img>` tags.  For each `<img>` tag, it make a new HTML request to fetch that so it can display it.  Now, if the `<img>` tags had absolute URLs, it would still show for you.  But if they have relative URLs (`<img src="/images/abc.png">`), then the browser is going to try to fetch them from your localhost web server, which does not exist.  You can try to scan the HTML and fetch those images.

Comment: This still doesn't tell me how I can get the functionality I am looking for with requests, which is to mimic a browser download. If I scan the HTML page and fetch those images, then I will probably need to go into the HTML file which has been downloaded separately, and replace the broken links with links pointing to the images, which have been downloaded separately. For something that is supposed to save time through mass downloading, this seems to be incredibly inefficient. Is there really no better way to mimic the functionality of "save as HTML?"

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what "save as HTML" does.  It rewrites the links.  It HAS to do that.  It's exactly as efficient as loading the page in a browser.  Remember that `wget` can clone an entire website for you, chasing all the local links and firing more downloads.